# get XML from Website in delphi application

Tags: xml, delphi

We have a desktop application(Delphi). In this application we are starting a website via Shellexecute.

The client fills the form on the website and clicks a button to generate XML.

What he wants is to recieve the XML in the delphi application. How can we push the XML from the website to the delphi deskptop application. We don't want the user to save the xml on the pc because they don't know how explorer works.

How can we get the XML from the website when he clicks the button?

Comment: Best is not to start external app. Embed a browser.

Comment: Thanks guys for your reply. Using Embed browser isn't a solution, because the website is from another client and his website doesn;t work in a embedded browser. TLama, Can you give me some information about XMLHTTP

Comment: That sounds bogus. Embedded browsers should display anything. By what mechanism is the xml going to be made available to you?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of entering form on website it would be better that you create form in your application for user to fill in, and then just send that data to website and you will get xml back with help of TIdHTTP component.

You can fill in form parameters with following procedure:

```
procedure AddFormParam(FormParams: TStringList; const Name, Value: string);
begin
  FormParams.Add(Name + '=' + Value);
end;
```

For instance if cgi expects fields with names: Name, Address, Message you will fill in parameters like this:

```
AddFormParam(FormParams, 'Name', NameValueString);
AddFormParam(FormParams, 'Address', AddressValueString);
AddFormParam(FormParams, 'Message', MessageValueString);
```

And then send it to server cgi:

```
function GetXML(HTTP: TIdHTTP; const FormCgiURL: string; FormParams: TStringList): string;
begin 
  Result := HTTP.Post(FormCgiURL, FormParams);
end;
```

Comment: Hi Dalija, The form(website) is from another compagny. The clients must fill the form on the website and we want the xml back in delphi.

Comment: When user clicks submit button on website form data will be sent to web server cgi for processing and that cgi will return XML you are looking for. Instead of triggering that process through web browser you can send form data cgi expects directly through your application. But you will have to recreate the form in your application and you must know in what format (name=values) form has to be posted to server.

Comment: @user the problem I have with your responses here are that on the one hand you indicate that this proprietary website must be used in a specific way with a specific browser, but then you expect us to know how this mystery site works. Why are you asking us rather than the website author?

Comment: I was thinking of asking the website builder to send the XML to our webservice. From there i can get the xml from my delphi application.

Comment: @user3552264: Dalija is right. What you are asking for can be done with Indy's `TIdHTTP`, or any other 3rd party HTTP component/library. The important piece is to look at the website's HTML to see what fields need to be submitted, or use a packet sniffer to see what a web browser transmits. Then you can replicate the same submission directly in your code without involving a web browser.